# Location of unidrv.dll in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I am trying to install some [fairly old printer software](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=3377077&swItemId=ma_81628_2&swEnvOid=4063) onto a Windows 7 machine and I keep getting prompted for  the location of "Unidrv.dll".

All the sites I googled try to tell me how to fix some other problem that would cause this... but all I need is THE LOCATION OF THE FILE, or even a good starting directory would be nice.

Comment: Check Event Viewer log, there must be log where is it looking this .dll for

Answer (score -1):

I eventually tried searching the C:\ drive for it and found one in:

```
C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\<specific folder name>\unidrv.dll.
```